# Check if vector contains at least one element from another vector in R

Tags: r

Say we have these two vectors:

```
vowels <- c("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y")
word <- c("c", "a", "t")
```

Is there a simple way to check if `word` contains at least one element from `vowels` and return either `TRUE` or `FALSE`?

Comment: `any(word %in% vowels)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R, you can try:

```
any(word %in% vowels) # See Johan Rosa's comment
# TRUE
```

Which first creates a vector of boolean values (`TRUE` or `FALSE`):

```
word %in% vowels
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

and then evaluates that vector to see if any of them are true (via `any`)

That is by far the easiest, but for other applications you could also use `grepl` which returns a vector of `TRUE` or `FALSE`

```
grepl(paste(vowels, collapse = "|"), word)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE

# Thus
any(grepl(paste(vowels, collapse = "|"), word))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: @Johan Rosa was first, but I'll vote for your answer

Comment: @JohanRosa thanks! Apologies, I truly didn't see the comment, but edited to point readers to it